# WPF XAML binding between an Observable collection in an object and ListView

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, listview, binding

I have this object :

```
public class ScriptEdi
{
    public int Identifiant { get; set; }
    public string CodeMessage { get; set; }
    public string Libelle { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ScriptEdiSection> Sections { get; set; }
}

public class ScriptEdiSection
{
    public string Name;
    public string Label;
}
```

In a Wpf Form, I want to show the Sections of an ScriptEdi Object

I do this:

`` `<Window x:Class="CBSToolZ.EdiForm"         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CBSToolZ"         mc:Ignorable="d"         Title="..." Height="480" Width="860" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Closing="Window_Closing"> ``

```
<Grid Margin="4,4,4,4">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="19*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ListView Margin="10,10,10,10" x:Name="EdiSectionsListView" >
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Paramètre" Width="240" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Libellé" Width="320" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Label}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And in .cs

`public partial class EdiForm : Window
{
public ScriptEdi scriptEdi;

```
public ScriptEdi scriptEdi;
public EdiForm(ScriptEdi _scriptEdi)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    scriptEdi = _scriptEdi;
    EdiSectionsListView.DataContext = scriptEdi;
    EdiSectionsListView.ItemsSource = scriptEdi.Sections;
}
```

And it's not working.... :-(

In my WpfForm I see then lines, but nothing writing in the columns of my grid....

[image]

Someone have and idea ?

Thanks

Comment: ScriptEdiSection contains fields, not properties. WPF data binding only works with public properties.

Comment: Supplement: Unless the life cycle of your binding object lasts until the program closed, please implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface on this class, otherwise there will be caused memory leak. (Even if you don't need to update properties, please still implement this interface.)